# Why isn´t SAS similarity valid with directed angles?

Tags: geometry

I´m reading EGMO and there the author leaves the exercise of finding a pair of triangles ABC and XYZ such that AB : XY = BC : YZ, the directed angles ∠BCA = ∠YZX, but triangles ABC and XYZ are not similar.

I think the example might be a pair of oppositely similar triangles, because the problem seems just valid for directly similar triangles. But i´m not sure if it is the correct example or if i´m misunderstanding the assumptions.

Comment: That's SSA, not SAS.

Answer (score 3):

A picture shows what may happen "against the intuition".
[image: math stackexchange 4200225]
We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{AB}{XY} &=1=\frac{BC}{YZ}&&\text{ and }
\\
\widehat{BCA} &=\widehat{YZX}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
But the two triangles are not similar, the angles between the sides which are proportional differ.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a question. This example that you show, is it the counterexample for the SSA criterion? I ask this because I´ve just noticed the question indeed is a SSA case, which would have this same counterexample if we were using directed angles or not. I´ve gone back to the book and I don´t understand why the author puts this as an exercise to prove the SAS criterion wrong for directed angles. In any case, could you please help me understand (regardless of the misplaced exercise of my initial question) why is the SAS criterion not valid for directed angles?

Comment: It is hard and maybe (at least didactically) not useful to define "SSA", this would lead to a regularly misleading vocabulary. At any rate, in the above picture we have two triangles, let us put them over each other $$\begin{aligned}&\Delta ABC\ ,\\&\Delta XYZ\ ,\end{aligned}$$ and we have equality for two proportions and a *directed* angle: $\frac {AB}{XY}=\frac{BC}{YZ}$, and the angles in $C=Z$ coincide (including their orientation). I simplified the given argument, maybe this new exposition is clearer...

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but for anyone reading the book, the Errata for the E.G.M.O has the problem listed as a mistake, it should be the normal SAS condition but with directed angles:[Link for EGMO errata](https://web.evanchen.cc/upload/geombook-errata.pdf)

To answer the question you may look at Theorem 2.4 where this very issue is the reason for the extra condition of "P lies in both of the segments AB and XY, or in neither segment." Referring to Figure 2.2B. the SAS condition with directed angles would lead us to "conclude" that YPA is similar to BPX.[Figure 2.2B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMPCd.png)